# Create a rewrite query string in apache which is not redirecting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, query-string

I would like to redirect all the traffic from `subdomain.domain.com` to `subdomain.domain.com/?appselect=app1`.

I followed some of the examples here: [Rewrite query string in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614473/rewrite-query-string-in-htaccess)
But they are not working for me for some reason. This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ /?appselect=app1 [PT,L]
```

But it just goes to the same page: `subdomain.domain.com`

Any help on this would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want redirect then add `R` flag:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)appselect=app1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /?appselect=app1 [QSA,L,R=302]
```

Comment: Thank you @anubhava but I got this error: This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: Just one more question, I'm planning to force to SSL in the future. Do you think that this is going to make me discard this rule and create a brand new one or can I recycle this rule to make it force it to https? And, is it possible to hide the real URL from the address bar and just show `subdomain.domain.com` to the user so the user don't see the query string attached to the URL? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: If you want to hide the real URL then remove `R=302` from above URL. And whenever you decide to use `SSL` then use that redirect rule before this rule.

Comment: Thanks anubhava, I removed R=302 and it is now showing apache test page, so is going somewhere else.

Comment: Removing `R=302` will still forward to `subdomain.domain.com/?appselect=app1` but it will be internal rewrite. Test it after clearing browser cache.

Comment: nope, It goes to the same page again (apache testing page). I even used another computer that has never accessed that site to make sure I wasn't caching :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77275/discussion-between-victor-and-anubhava).

Comment: May I know why you removed accepted mark from this answer after I supported you for so long and resolve your problem?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake I did.

Comment: No issues mate. Just to let you know Julio's answer will cause a redirect loop.

Comment: I just meant to vote up for his answer but I clicked in accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically doing something like this would work. It worked for my server.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /?appselect=app1 [QSA,L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RewriteRule ^$ /?appselect=app1 [PT,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but it goes to the same page: subdomain.domain.com