# rewrite url with query string issue

Tags: .htaccess

i have a issue with some rewriting url with htaccess.
i need the following:

old: `mydomain.com/categorie/details.php?companyid=10`

new: `mydomain.com/item/?p=10`

where i want to catch and replace the numbers (of several id) dynamically.
I've read the answer of the other question but that's only replace the query string. I quess i need some regex but i'm a newbee with that..

i have this in htaccess:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/categorie/details\.php$
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^companyID=([0-9]*)$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.mydomain.com/item/?p=%1/ [R=301,L]`

Before i migrate i've tested this and it worked fine, for some reasons it won't work anymore after migration.
Do i miss something? Is this the wrong approach?

Kind regards,
Tom.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewrite query string in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614473/rewrite-query-string-in-htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this line

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.mydomain.com/item/?p=%1/ [R=301,L]`

Put the ful URL like this :

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/item/?p=%1/ [R=301,L]`

Also put this `[NC]` ,nocase to accept  upper-case and lower-case, at the end of this line

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^companyID=([0-9]*)$ [NC]`.

So , your rules should look like this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/categorie/details\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^companyID=([0-9]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/item/?p=%1 [R=301,L]
```

To sumerize all these rules more , do this :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^companyID=([0-9]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^categorie/details\.php$ http://www.example.com/item/?p=%1 [R=301,L]
```

And as you menthioned that it is same domain , let them be like this :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^companyID=([0-9]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^categorie/details\.php$  /item/?p=%1 [R=301,L]
```

No need to full URL.

**Note:** clear browser cache then test

Comment: Hi Mohammed, thanks for responding. I've tried the second and third rules you suggest, but it won't work. (clear all caches) There is no redirecting. Is that because of the files of the Original url aren't there anymore?

Comment: @Thomw please paste your full htaccess , did you put RewriteEngine On at the begining ? are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled?

Comment: Oké solved! There was some hack with other redirects (wordpress) Thanks! You saved my day!

Comment: @Thomw glad to help and if you feel my solution is solved your problen don't forget to accept it , thanks